# How to access the .setup function on a feather-sequelize object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I want to nest a service behind another one, just as described in [the FAQ](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#how-do-i-do-nested-or-custom-routes) and [this issue](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/670)

As I understood, you need the `.setup` property to get access to the `app` object, on which you can add a listener that you link to your service. So far so good.

However, the service I would need to do that on is not a custom service, on which the `setup` property is readily available, but a `feathers-sequelize` service, which seems to be built else where, the .class.js is not even present.

Searching around, I ve seen you can still access the property with the protoype, but not I am reticent in modifying it without knowing it to be something supported.

TL:DR: How to nest a feather-sequelize service behind another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend the existing Sequelize ES6 class [as documented here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#classes-es6):

```
const { Service } = require( 'feathers-sequelize');

class MyService extends Service {
  setup(app, path) {
    this.app = app;
    // Do stuff here
  }
}

app.use('/todos', new MyService({
  paginate: {
    default: 2,
    max: 4
  }
}));
```